# Pandas: Merge two Dataframes (same columns) with condition... How can i improve this code?

Tags: python, pandas

(Sorry, my english skills is bad...)

I'm studying with public data.
I'm trying merge two excel files with some condition.
I tried multi-loop code, but it's too slow...
How can I improve my code?

Please help me TvT

## DataStructure example is

old data(entire_file.xlsx)

```
            KeyCode       Date                     Something
    0       aaa           2020-01-01 00:00:00      adaf
    1       bbb           2020-02-01 00:00:00      awd
    2       ccc           2020-03-01 00:00:00      feq
    ...
    6000    aewi          2020-03-03 00:00:00      awefeaw
```

new data(file2.xlsx)

```
            KeyCode       Date                     Something
    1       bbb           2020-06-01 20:00:00      aafewfaewfaw
    2       ccc           2020-06-01 20:00:00      dfqefqe
    3       new           2020-06-01 20:00:00      newrow
```

hope(file3.xlsx)

```
            KeyCode       Date                     Something
    0       aaa           2020-01-01 00:00:00      adaf
    1       bbb           2020-06-01 20:00:00      aafewfaewfaw
    2       ccc           2020-06-01 20:00:00      dfqefqe
    ...
    6000    aewi          2020-03-03 00:00:00      awefeaw
    6001    new           2020-06-01 20:00:00      newrow
```

**Code:**

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    %matplotlib notebook
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    data = pd.read_excel('fulldata_01_01_01_P_병원.xlsx', index_col='번호')
    tmp = pd.read_excel('(20200601~20200607)_01_01_01_P_병원.xlsx', index_col='번호')
    
    print('{} is tmp rows count'.format(len(tmp.index)))
    print('{} is data rows count'.format(len(data.index)))
    
    new_data = pd.DataFrame([])
    for j in range(len(tmp.index)):
        ischange = False;
        isexist = False;
        for i in range(len(data.index)):
            if (data.iloc[i].loc['KeyCode'] == tmp.iloc[j].loc['KeyCode']) and (data.iloc[i].loc['Date'] < tmp.iloc[j].loc['Date']) :
                ischange = True
                data.iloc[i] = tmp.iloc[j]
                break
            elif (data.iloc[i].loc['KeyCode'] == tmp.iloc[j].loc['KeyCode']) :
                isexist = True
                break
                
        if ischange :
            print('{} is change'.format(j))
        elif isexist :
            print('{} is exist'.format(j))
        elif not ischange and not isexist :
            print('{} is append'.format(j))
            new_data.append(tmp.iloc[j], ignore_index=True)
    
    data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)
    print('{} is tmp rows count'.format(len(tmp.index)))
    print('{} is data rows count'.format(len(data.index)))
```

But... it is not working...

Comment: can you explain what the condition suppose to do? how do you want to merge the files?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the new data or the updated but not existing:

```
result = pd.concat([data, tmp], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
result = result.sort_values(['KeyCode', 'Date'], ascending=[True,True])  # order to find duplicates later
result = result.drop_duplicates('KeyCode', keep='first')  # drop old data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very interesting. You want to merge two dataframe but they have intersection,so your code use a loop to check the temp line whether unique.

But the pandas have a function help us to remove intersection between two dataframe.

This function will solve your problem.

[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Hope could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do both operations (common and new lines) in 2 steps:

```
# merge common keys (beware the index...)
common = pd.merge(data[['KeyCode']].reset_index(), temp, on='KeyCode'
                  ).set_index('index')
data.loc[common.index] = common

# add new keys
new_data = temp.loc[~temp['KeyCode'].isin(data['KeyCode'])]
data = data.append(new_data, sort=False)
```

With you sample data, it would give:

```
     KeyCode                 Date     Something
0        aaa  2020-01-01 00:00:00          adaf
1        bbb  2020-06-01 20:00:00  aafewfaewfaw
2        ccc  2020-06-01 20:00:00       dfqefqe
...
6000    aewi  2020-03-03 00:00:00       awefeaw
6001     new  2020-06-01 20:00:00        newrow
```

---

Alternatively, you could directly use an outer join and then combine the columns:

```
data = data.merge(temp, how='outer', on = 'KeyCode')
for col in columns:
    data[col] = data[col+'_y'].combine_first(data[col+'_x'])
data = data.drop(columns = [col+suffix for col in columns
                            for suffix in ['_x', '_y']])
```